# Scroll to view in ng-repeat items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

have horizontal items that are created using ng-repeat, the items are sometimes outside of the screen, so a scroll bar is present. when a user clicks an item that can be half way out the screen view, how do I go about bringing it to view ?

what I did was, set `<div id={{$index}} .../>` to each of the items, and using `$location.hash(index)` in my js code and then call

```
$anchoreScroll()
```

from some reason it doesnt work. any ideas ?

plnkr example:

```
[http://plnkr.co/edit/iBe71wDBFfhx69TwugmS?p=preview][1]
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/iBe71wDBFfhx69TwugmS?p=preview

Comment: I see it working. You need to explain better what doesn't work.

Comment: using IE it seems to work, I am using chrome and it doesnt work the same way it does in IE

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this doesn't work with Chrome, I had to implement my own scrolling mechanism